# Run vbscript on server as scheduled task

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, vbscript

I've written two scripts in vbs, one iterates through a bunch (+10000) of folders on our server and creates a shortcut in a specific folder to any folder that has a specific name. ('ax' followed by the number and name of a project). This way we can use this folder of shortcuts to search for a specific project folder instead of having to go through the entire folder tree with Windows search (which takes alot longer)

The other one iterates through another folder containing pictures of these projects. The script creates a shortcut to the picture folder in the corresponding project folder.
The first script takes about an hour to run, the second one multiple hours (since it goes through a lot more folders).

Right now I have a scheduled task on my own laptop for these scripts. The first one runs every day at lunch, the other one runs every Monday evening (since we leave our pc's on anyway for a full system virus scan). 
However we would like these scripts to run on the server so that they are run even when my laptop isn't turned on (like when I'm sick or on holiday).

Now, my question is: Does running these scripts (let's say the first one every night, the other one every weekend) pose any threat to our server in terms of stability? Evidently we don't want to come into work on Monday and find out this script has crashed our server. 
Note: So far I've had no problems whatsoever when running them from my laptop, but it was completely passive apart from the script.

PS: Before you say anything about the scripts being written in vbs, I know this is a dying language but they are based on other scripts already in use in our company. So rewriting them in another language isn't really an option for now.

Comment: what are the other thing running on server ? what kind of disk you have ? Maybe ou can make your script as service and doing just a part of the job each hour for example ? shortcut has to be recreated each time ? is it web based project (can use virtual directory) ? maybe you can stop to loop a folder if a project is found, or thing like that to prevent too much hdd access

Comment: The server is mainly used as file server. Running part of the script every hour isn't ideal because we want it running when noone is accessing the shortcuts. All the shortcuts are deleted and recreated every time to prevent dead links. The project folders contain mostly Autocad drawings and pdf-files, no special settings. The script is already as efficient as I can make it, exiting the loop when the required folder is found, etc...

Comment: maybe you can store in a file all folders + linked shorcuts as string, and on next treatment recrate shortcuts only if shortcut doesn't work. like that user will not have shortcut deleted while they access it